# How to split a long string into mutiable strings depending on a specific number of characters?

Tags: vb.net, string

I have a long string of Hex values, and I want to split it into
several strings.

For example:

```
str = "313233343536373839"; which is "123456789" in Hexadecimal
```

I want the result to be this way:

(if the number divided on to is 3, means each line consists of 6
 value.)

```
str =  "313233"
str =  str + "343536"
str =  str + "373839"
```

and so on...

I've searched for a way to do so, but everything uses `.Split` and this last requires a splitter character, which in this case one does not exist.  How can I split this properly?

Comment: what if doesn't divide by 3?

Comment: 3 is just a random number specified by the user and the string is divided on that number. for example if the string length = 20, and the number is 5, so 20 / 5 = 4 (each char in a single string)

Comment: by the way 313233343536373839 is 458D410FD4B204F in hex

Comment: now seriously! you're focusing on that! :) i'm turning a text file has "12345..9" into bytes, then convert these bytes into hex values.

Comment: Please clarify what do you mean by "mutiable string" and narrow down your question to particular case: it's overly broad, unclear and, frankly, looks like a request for code-writing service. Thanks and regards,

Comment: plus, 1 =31, 2=32, 3=33 and so on,, it's really equals 313233343536373839, check your info again..

Comment: oh i apologize, it's just i want to split the string (which are hex-values) into a Sub consists of the string divided, i already gave an example, and it's clear, but can't find an idea to split this string, as there is no splitter to depends on using the ".Split" method.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to split string *str* into *numParts* parts? Define an array:

```
Dim strArray() As String
```

Then have your user input the number of parts:

```
Dim numParts As Integer
numParts = Console.readLine()
'you might want to put some validation in there to check it is a number
```

Redim your array to be the number of parts-1 (as arrays start at 0)

```
ReDim strArray(numParts - 1)
```

Finally, set a for loop up to split your string into parts:

```
For i as Integer = 0 to numParts - 1
    strArray(i) = str.Substring(i * Math.Floor(str.Length / numParts), Math.Floor(str.Length / numParts))
Next
```

And that should work (though I can't access VS at the moment so it is untested). It will truncate the last digits if length doesn't divide by numParts

As an aside: Don't ask homework questions here.

Comment: Brilliant, that's the idea, i'm gonna give it a try... yeah sorry about that i needed just an idea not a full sol. but thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

this will do what you asked

```
Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Dim myHex As Long = &H458D410FD4B204F
    Dim myStr As String = myHex.ToString
    Dim myDiv As Integer = 3
    Dim myPart As Integer = myStr.Length \ myDiv

    If myStr.Length > 0 AndAlso myStr.Length Mod myDiv = 0 Then
        For i As Integer = 0 To myDiv - 1
            Console.WriteLine("str = {1}{0}", myStr.Substring(i * myPart, myPart), If(i > 0, "str + ", ""))
        Next
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("my string {0} length doesn't divide by {1}", myStr, myDiv)
    End If

    Console.Read()
End Sub

End Module
```